# tmux - disable beep on attach/detach

Tags: linux, bash, tmux, beep

I am using mcabber with beep option inside tmux. I want mcabber to beep,but don't want tmux to beep on startup, attach or detach.

```
# disable sound bell
set -g bell-action none
# disable visual bell
set -g visual-bell off
```

I found this, but this disables mcabber beeps and do not disable attach/detach beep. How to disable attach/detach beep in tmux?

Comment: Didn't know there was an attach/detach beep. Sure it's not something in your shell (which will be spawned on a new tmux session) and probably give a PS1 when you detach?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to set one more option. This should work:

```
set -g bell-action all
set -g visual-bell off
set -g bell-on-alert off
```

Not sure if this will work with mcabber but it should disable the tmux bell.

Comment: It appears that it's actually `set -g bell-action any`.